# SQL Server Stored Procedure Timing Out In SSRS Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a stored procedure that I've tested over and over again in SQL Server Management Studio and it works fine, returning results in roughly 3 seconds; however, when I add the Stored Procedure as the Query Type for a new DataSet in Report Builder and attempt to, either run the report or execute the SP through the built-in `Query Designer` the execution call times-out.  I haven't even used the dataset yet in any area within the report (Tablix's or Charts).

I've made sure that the `Data Sources` credentials are setup properly and even tested the connection to the DB and received a successful connection statement.

I have the Dataset `Time out` property set to `0` which should mean no timeout.  Clearly, the timeout I'm receiving is being handled by the SQL Server rather than the Report Builder in this particular case.

What would make the Stored Procedure execute properly and efficiently (speed-wise) when executed from the server, but time-out when executed from Report Builder?

I'm running 2008 R2.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tested in SSMS using the same parameters you are passing from SSRS ?

Comment: Not sure how did you set time out to 0, usually I open the report file (XML format), and modify the time out directly. I can't remember exactly where but should be the object when call the stored procedure. Dataset time out (you mentioned) might be different to the proc exec time out.

Comment: You could use SQL Profiler to work out exactly what is being submitted to the DB, then pick that up and troubleshoot it directly.

Comment: The SQL Server database engine does not timeout queries.  Query timeouts errors occur on the client side so it seems the dataset `Time out` property is not being honored.  The cause of the performance difference is likely different execution plans.  See http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html for reasons why the plans might be different.

Comment: @M.Ali, yes, that's what I was trying to convey in my OP. I have tested in SSMS with the same params and it runs correctly and returns in 3-4 seconds (everytime, no exceptions)

Comment: @JohnJin, I set the timeout directly in the dataset creator wizard dialog box. When selecting which data source and stored procedure to use another option box is to set the timeout. 0 equates to no timeout (which is what I have it set to)

Comment: So, this morning I come back and run the Stored Procedure from the Query Designer screen in Report Builder and everything works.  I have literally touched nothing and changed nothing.  Perhaps the server was just overloaded with requests yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most time-out errors occur during query processing. If you are encountering time-out errors, try increasing the query time-out value. Make sure to adjust the report execution time-out value so that it is larger than the query time-out. The time period should be sufficient to complete both query and report processing.

Thanks
Venky